# Modulo 'image' não roda no iPython3

Tags: python, processamento-de-imagens

Ainda sou iniciante no mundo da programação, e recentemente me deparei com um problema que ainda está sem solução.

Estou usando um livro on-line interativo para aprender python (How to think like a computer scientist). Em um dos capítulos, o livro ensina a trabalhar com processamento de imagens. Como o livro é interativo, ele oferece uma própria plataforma para escrever e rodar as linhas de código, o ActiveCode. O problema começa quando na ferramenta de desenvolvimento do livro, o modulo "image" se encontra presente e funcionando, mas na versão 3 do python que eu uso, não.

A versão que o livro trabalha é a mesma que eu trabalho. Uso a ferramenta iPython3 notebook rodando no Firefox para programar. Quando eu rodo um programa simples como:

```
import image

p = image.Pixel(45, 76, 200)
print(p.getRed())
```

O programa deveria me retornar o valor "45", entretanto uma mensagem de erro é exibida:

> ```
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-7-83aeecd92382> in <module>()
> ----> 1 import image
>   2 
>   3 p = image.Pixel(45,76,200)
>   4 print(p.getRed())
>
> ImportError: No module named 'image'
> ```

Enfim, como faço para resolver esse problema, e conseguir rodar esse modulo no meu computador?

Eu li em alguns lugares pessoas falando para usar a pil library com o comando `from PIL import Image`, mas não funcionou. Aparentemente são coisas diferentes.

Especificação do sistema: Elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64-bit) Construído sobre Ubuntu 14.04
notebook Lenovo Y430

Segue o link do site para vocês darem uma olhada: [How To Think Like a Computer Scientist](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/MoreAboutIteration/2DimensionalIterationImageProcessing.html#dimensional-iteration-image-processing)

Comment: normalmente a biblioteca `image` não vem instalada por padrão no python, instale a biblioteca `Pillow`

Comment: Já tentou utilizar import Image
?

Comment: Sim, e o erro persiste o mesmo.

mportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e90509fea2a2> in <module>()
----> 1 import Image
      2 
      3 p = image.Pixel(45,76,200)
      4 print(p.getRed())

ImportError: No module named 'Image'

Comment: Segundo o site dos desenvolvedores, para instalar o Pillow, eu preciso desinstalar o PIL. como eu desinstalo a biblioteca PIL?

Comment: Usando esses comandos:

Pra desinstalar: pip uninstall PIL

Comment: Tenta desinstalar o Pil e instalar o Pillow

Comment: acabei de desinstalar o PIL, instalar o Pillow e reiniciar o computador. o erro continua.

Comment: mesmo com o Pillow instalado, o ipython3 notebook nao roda esse modulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/installation.html#warnings) do Pillow, será preciso desinstalar o PIL:

> Pillow and PIL cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL.

Logo, desinstale o PIL e instale o Pillow:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install Pillow
```

Para utilizar o Pillow:

```
''' Pegar o red do RGB de um pixel da imagem '''
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('yourimage.jpg')
im = im.convert('RGB')
r, g, b = im.getpixel((1, 1))
print(r)
```